# Clone element and repeat until viewport is filled

Tags: javascript

Learning JavaScript and this is my first ever real 'project''

I've created a loop to check that the .background element is smaller than the client, if it is then add the the slice node until the .background element is the same height as the client.

The issue is that too many slice nodes are being added and sometimes crashing the browser.

Also, is there a way to clone the HTML node and repeat it instead of using:

```
background.innerHTML += '<span class=slice></span>';
```

If is there a better way of doing what I'm trying to do then please do let me know!

**JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/8ryAD/11/

**HTML**

```
<div class="master">

    <a id="btn-nav">
        <span></span>
        <span>Menu</span>
        <span></span>
    </a>

    <nav id="main-nav">

            <div class="background">

                <div class="slice"></div>


            </div>

    </nav>

</div><!-- end master -->
```

**JS**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var w = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var menuBtn = document.getElementById('btn-nav');
    var slice = document.querySelectorAll('.slice');
    var background = document.getElementsByClassName('background')[0];

    //var mainNavHeight = document.getElementById('main-nav').clientHeight;
    //var slideAdd = slice.cloneNode(true);
    //var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;


    menuBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {

        menuBtn.classList.add('open');

            for(var i = background.clientHeight; i < w; i++) {      
                background.innerHTML += '<span class=slice></span>';

                            //for(var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++){
                //  slice[i].style.opacity = 1;
                // }
            }

    }, false);

}());
```

Comment: Yes. There are better ways to make your div grow, and we let you know. BTW: You can get the whole page/window height value, your background div height, your master div value... What about some simple arithmetic and setting the height property accordingly?

Comment: Hmm ok. Let me try again.

Answer (score 0):

Done it. If someone knows a better way of doing this then please do let me know! Thanks.

```
var slice = document.querySelectorAll('.slice');
var menuBtn = document.getElementById('btn-nav');
var b = document.getElementsByClassName('background')[0];
var a = document.getElementById('main-nav').clientHeight

menuBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {

    menuBtn.classList.add('open');

        for(var i = b.clientHeight; i < a; i++) {   

          if(b.clientHeight == a) {

            break;
          } else {
            b.innerHTML += '<span class=slice></span>';
          }
        }

}, false);
```

Comment: If you're looking for code feedback the Code Review SE site is more applicable.